# Configuring LPTIM Parameters with the STM32L4

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, arm, timer, low-power

I bought an STM32L433 Nucleo-64 board (STM32L433RCTxP) and I am trying to learn more about the LPTIM peripheral. I am experimenting with setting up the LPTIM1 peripheral so that it generates an interrupt every 1 second, and the LPTIM1 interrupt handler would do some trivial task.

This is how I am setting up my LPTIM1:

```
/* Note: SYSCLK, HCLK, PCLK1, PCLK2 are all 16MHz running on HSI */
static void MX_LPTIM1_Init(void)
{
  hlptim1.Instance = LPTIM1;
  hlptim1.Init.Clock.Source = LPTIM_CLOCKSOURCE_APBCLOCK_LPOSC;
  hlptim1.Init.Clock.Prescaler = LPTIM_PRESCALER_DIV128;
  hlptim1.Init.Trigger.Source = LPTIM_TRIGSOURCE_SOFTWARE;
  hlptim1.Init.OutputPolarity = LPTIM_OUTPUTPOLARITY_HIGH;
  hlptim1.Init.UpdateMode = LPTIM_UPDATE_IMMEDIATE;
  hlptim1.Init.CounterSource = LPTIM_COUNTERSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  hlptim1.Init.Input1Source = LPTIM_INPUT1SOURCE_GPIO;
  hlptim1.Init.Input2Source = LPTIM_INPUT2SOURCE_GPIO;
  if (HAL_LPTIM_Init(&hlptim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(LPTIM1_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPTIM1_IRQn);

  /* 65535 is the value loaded into LPTIM1's ARR register */
  HAL_LPTIM_Counter_Start_IT(&hlptim1, 65535);
}
```

The interrupt handler currently looks like this:

```
static uint32_t counter = 0;

/**
  * @brief  Autoreload match callback in non blocking mode 
  * @param  hlptim : LPTIM handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_LPTIM_AutoReloadMatchCallback(LPTIM_HandleTypeDef *hlptim)
{
    /* Blink onboard LED */
    if(counter >= 2)
    {
        /* TODO: Do some task here */
        DoRandomStuffHere();
        
        counter = 0;
    }
    
    counter++;
}
```

The code above does not produce an interrupt every 1 second, but the function `DoRandomStuffHere()` does get executed *almost* every second. I measured the timing with a stopwatch and the function seems to execute periodically at slightly higher than 1Hz (maybe at around 0.9 seconds between each execution).

I am wondering what the equation looks like for the LPTIMx peripherals. I thought it was similar to TIMx timer peripherals where:

TIMx_Frequency = SYSCLK/((Period + 1) * (Prescaler + 1))

and the Period = value that goes into ARR. If I were to use this formula for the LPTIM1, it does not come close to the 1Hz I am expecting.

What sort of parameters would I need to generate an LPTIM1 interrupt every second? Thanks!

For comparison, I have also included code where the TIM2 generates an interrupt every second:

```
/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{
  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 15999;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 999;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(TIM2_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM2_IRQn);

  /* Start TIM2 Interrupt - 1sec interrupt */
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(htim->Instance == TIM2)
    {
      /* TODO: Do some task here */
      DoRandomStuffHere();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obtained the equation from a different Q&A forum, and the update rate (in Hz) is:
\begin{equation}
UpdateRate_{LPTIM} = \frac{ClockSource}{(Prescaler)(ARR + 1)}
\end{equation}
Based on the equation above, I should be getting an update rate of 1.9Hz, so I will double-check my measurements with a Logic Analyzer (at 1.9Hz, `DoRandomStuffHere()` should be executing periodically and **slower** than 1 second in between each function execution).

In the code above, the only way to slow it down is to change the clock source's frequency or to use a different clock source that is slower (such as internal LSI).